# How to know if error from dotnet build command with powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core

I want custom script when my dotnet build command failed.
How to get errors list or not success flag when the 'dotnet build' failed with errors compilation for example, or when 'dotnet test' failed, with powershell.

I want equivalent code

```
dotnet test
if (!$result.Successful) {
    $errorMessage = ""
    if ($result.Error -ne $null) {
        $errorMessage = $result.Error.Message
    }
    Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error;] error"
    Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]"
    Exit -1
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can merge the standard output and error streams with the `>` stream redirection operator, and then inspect the `$LASTEXITCODE` automatic variable to see if the call succeeded or not:

```
# Merge all streams into stdout
$result = dotnet test *>&1

# Evaluate success/failure
if($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0)
{
    # Success
}
else
{
    # Failed, you can reconstruct stderr strings with:
    $ErrorString = $result -join [System.Environment]::NewLine
}
```

Comment: In case this happens to you.... if your prompt function calls an executable (eg. git) then this will will set `$LASTEXITCODE` losing any value from the "last" command.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by just using exec in PS.

```
exec { dotnet build $projectFile -o $targetDir -c Release }
```

Comment: Since 22/06/2019 (and probably some update in the Windows Server 2012 VPS) I cannot use exec enymore.    The term 'exec' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.